# Get previous calculated value from a row and update that value in next row same column and subtract with that .. Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my existing table in SQL server. I just want find GAP for each ChildID group ie, ClosingStock - Demand

```
Existing Table:

ParentID    ChildID   Demand    ClosingStock  BasicFinishDate
2537        3064        8           161         9/18/2018
5407        6238        25          161         9/28/2018
5056        6238        30          161         9/28/2018
5056        6238        10          161         10/3/2018
5407        6238        45          161         10/5/2018
5498        8462        3           161         9/10/2018
5498        8462        9           161         9/27/2018
5498        8462        144         161         10/3/2018
5498        8462        1           161         10/4/2018


Expected Result:

ParentID   ChildID   Demand   ClosingStock  Gap        BasicFinishDate
2537        3064        8           161     153         9/18/2018
5407        6238        25          161     136         9/28/2018
5056        6238        30          136     106         9/28/2018
5056        6238        10          106     96          10/3/2018
5407        6238        45          96      51          10/5/2018
5498        8462        3           161     158         9/10/2018
5498        8462        9           158     149         9/27/2018
5498        8462        144         149     5           10/3/2018
5498        8462        1           5       4           10/4/2018
```

Gap is calculated as ClosingStock -(minus) Demand.

ClosingStock column also has to get updated with previous Gap value if it has similar ChildID

.Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you get to values 136 and 106 in the 3th row ?

Comment: that is gap 136 and 106 belongs to ChildID group 6238. 161-25 is 136 and 136-30 is 106... ClosingStock - Demand is GAP

Comment: Closing Stock column has to get updated and for GAP calculation it should take updated Closing Stock value

Comment: Can you explain this logic in the question please. If people dont have to read all the comments to get the info they need, you might get more answers

Comment: To get this done you need to make sure your table is always sorted correct. What column can we use to sort on for this ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope below query will help you.

```
SELECt 
        ParentID
        ,ChildID
        ,Demand
        ,ClosingStock
        ,ClosingStock-Demand as gap
        ,BasicFinishDate
FROM 
(
SELECT 
        ParentID 
        ,ChildID
        ,Demand 
        ,ClosingStock - (CASE WHEN Demand=DemandTotal THEN 0 ELSE LAG(DemandTotal)OVER(PARTITION by ChildID Order by BasicFinishDate asc, PArentId desc ) END)  as ClosingStock
        ,BasicFinishDate
FROM 
(
SELECT  
        ParentID 
        ,ChildID
        ,Demand 
        ,SUM(Demand) OVER (partition by ChildID ORDER BY BasicFinishDate asc, PArentId desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS DemandTotal 
        ,ClosingStock
        ,BasicFinishDate
FROM #test
)R
)Q
```